# Get every guest meet every other guest at least once

Tags: algorithms

Say I'm throwing a weekly dinner party where I got 10 tables and 60 guests. How can I get everyone seated each week so everyone gets to meet each other *at least* once in the minimum amount of weeks?

I've searched about it and found The Social Golf Problem, but in that problem you cannot have repetitions, and that's not an issue for me.

Is there a way to come up with an algorithm that returns the list of groups in each table each week for *n* tables and *k* guests?

Comment: Presumably you must have exactly $6$ guests per table?

Comment: There is no rules on how many people should sit together, but the guests should be spread evenly. So in this case, there should be $6$ guests per table, but in a case where I have $65$ guests and $10$ tables, there would be some tables with $6$ guests and others with $7$ guests.

Comment: I haven't much idea how to tackle this, but maybe looking at small cases might help?

Comment: The [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html) can tell us the minimum number of groups of six (number of tables) is between $120$ and $128$, but it does not address the aspect of seating ten tables simultaneously (so that we need ten disjoint blocks of six for each week).  The Social Golfer Problem, by contrast, is about *packing designs*, a kind of dual to the problem of covering designs.  The keyword for seating ten tables at once (the entire set of guests) is "resolvable" (so you want a minimum resolvable covering design).

Comment: Trivially it cannot take less than 12 weeks (since each guest meets 5 others in a week and they need to meet 59 guests). I'm aware of a social golfer 7-week solution which might be a good start (at the end of that time every guest has sat with 35 of the 59, leaving 24 they haven't yet sat with).